How do I get a list of all users using Moodle web services without getting a server timeout
When I use core_user_get_users with lastname && % || email && % to get a list of all users, I get a "504 Gateway Time-out" response.
Is there any other ways to provide the same result, without getting this error?
What about returning all the users from a specific tenant? Then I could store the users per tenant instead, but a complete userlist is preferred.
Specifically, I tried:
criteria[0][key] = lastname
criteria[0][value] = %

Which returned:
<html>

<head>
    <title>504 Gateway Time-out</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>nginx</center>
</body>

</html>

I expected:
List of all users
